# Sharepoint 2010 search won't index custom fields

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a managed metadata field, but it isn't showing up in my crawled columns.  It is a custom field. I am not sure what is wrong, but when I search, my only result is the view all items page that relates to the list.  It doesn't seem to search the list items themselves. I don't know if that is relevant or not.

I added this column to my view just incase it was needed, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you added the new columns, it may not have been crawled yet by the search service.  If it has been a while and you know that the crawler should have picked it up, you might try to delete the search index and run a new full crawl to pick it up correctly.  It may be something as simple as an incremental crawl indexing the list as a whole and not the item itself.